# How to map new class to existing in entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this two property in entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<OrderItemEntity> orderItems;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Where(clause = "interaction_code!='TERMINATE'")
private Set<OrderItemEntity> orderItemsWithoutTerminationOrders;
```

I want now to add anotation to map this orderItemsWithoutTerminationOrders to orderItems.

Any suggestion how to do that or is it possible??

Comment: Maybe you can use @Embeddable class and than add it to your entity?

Comment: i dont think that will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't map that, but you don't need to do it. You can just create this collection on demand or in a post load lifecycle listener:

```
private transient Set<OrderItemEntity> orderItemsWithoutTerminationOrders;
@PostLoad
void init() {
  orderItemsWithoutTerminationOrders = orderItems.stream().filter(o -> o.getInteractionCode() != InteractionCode.TERMINATE).collect(toSet());
}
```

I wouldn't recommend this though as that is a projection for which you should use a DTO approach and I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(OrderEntity.class)
public interface OrderDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    @Mapping("customer.name")
    String getCustomerName();
    @Mapping("orderItems[interactionCode != fully.qualified.name.InteractionCode.TERMINATE]")
    Set<OrderItemDto> getOrderItems();

    @EntityView(OrderItemEntity.class)
    interface OrderItemDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`OrderDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, OrderDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<OrderDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!